# Using matplotlib to create a spectrogram of a wavfile

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
sample_rate, X = wav.read("/Users/sinaastani/Downloads/partynextdoor.wav")
X = scipy.mean(X, axis=1)
plt.specgram(X, Fs=sample_rate, xextent=(0,30))
```

I get an error whenever I run the code above:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:7017: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
  Z = 10. * np.log10(spec)
```

This occurs with several wav files that I have tried. I'm simply trying to replicate an example from "Building Machine Learning Systems with Python - Second Edition".

The wavfile.read function returns a numpy array. It looks like at the beginning and end of this array, there are a bunch of 0 values so when it tries to calculate log(0) it is undefined. What is the appropriate to deal with this? Should I simply get rid of 0 values from the array?

Comment: Why don't you try what happens? Since missing values could be a problem for later analysis, you can also set them to `nan` or to the lowest positive number you like, `X[X == 0] = scipy.nan` or `X[X == 0] = 1.e-18`. However, I'm not sure if this can really be the problem. I tried deliberately setting some values to `0` and the code still runs fine for the files I tried. Which line in your code produces the above error?

Comment: Its the corner values of the numpy array, which is the variable 'X' in my sample. The call to specgram performs a log computation using the array values, so thats what is causing the error.

Comment: My point is more that you can call `plt.specgram(np.zeros(1000))` without getting an error. Zeros in the array can thus not be the error's cause. Neither can `nan`s or `inf`s.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter NFFT of plt.specgram(). Because this parameter defaults to 256, it causes the error. You can increase this number by multiplying it to 2 to the extent by which the error disappears. Try 512 - 1024 - 2048 , ... and the problem is solved!:)